# Remove SSIDs without name in iwlist wlan scan

Tags: awk, raspbian, wpa-supplicant, iwlwifi, wpa-cli

In Raspbian when I'm running command  `iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID` i'm getting results without SSID on it  like below

```
            ESSID:"OpenWrt"
            ESSID:"dlink"
            ESSID:"tplink"
            ESSID:"linksys"
            ESSID:"tenda"
            ESSID:"pi"
            ESSID:""
            ESSID:"somessid"
            ESSID:""
            ESSID:"router"
            ESSID:""
            ESSID:""
            ESSID:""
```

I don't why I getting this blank SSID lines. my work environment may have some hidden network. not sure. but I need to remove this before send to front end processing. how can I achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'ESSID:"..*"'
            ESSID:"OpenWrt"
            ESSID:"dlink"
            ESSID:"tplink"
            ESSID:"linksys"
            ESSID:"tenda"
            ESSID:"pi"
            ESSID:"somessid"
            ESSID:"router"
```

- `.` meta character matches any character
- `.*` will match zero or more characters
- Can also use `grep -E 'ESSID:".+"'` which will match at least one character between the double quotes